# Updating Canvas Image dynamically using PaperJs

Tags: image, html5-canvas, updating, raster, paperjs

I have an image  element with src pointing to an Handler (asp.net), and this image being used as source for Raster (PaperJs) object defined as global object and updated during window.load.

```
var raster;
paper.install(window);    
function WindowOnLoad() {    
    raster = new paper.Raster('MainContent_imageData');
    raster.position = paper.view.center;
    window.paper.view.draw();
}
```

The above code is loading image onto the canvas on first load then the image element is getting updated through a button click which is associated with callback  control (ComponentArt callback control) but the canvas is not, it displays blank.

Then I created an handler that is being called after the callback is complete but it also didn't work.

```
function CallBackCompleted(sender,eventArgs) {
    var imgData = document.getElementById('MainContent_imageData');
    raster.image = imgData ;
    raster.position = window.paper.view.center;
    window.paper.view.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code fixed the issue. The raster object is added as a child object on layer[0] removed all the other objects except children[0], which refers to the raster object.

```
function CallBackCompleted(sender,eventArgs) {
    if(window.paper.project.layers[0].hasChildren())
         window.paper.project.layers[0].removeChildren(1);

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = document.getElementById('MainContent_imageData').src;
    imageObj.onload = function () {
    window.paper.project.layers[0].children[0].setImage(imageObj);
    window.paper.project.layers[0].children[0].position = window.paper.view.center;
    window.paper.view.draw();
  }
}
```